# Play Framework: Entity not having primary key column named id

Tags: jpa, playframework

I want to use existing database. Entity table has a column named code to be used as primary key.

Probably a simple annotation but I am new to Play Framework and JPA.

Thank you

Comment: Then read a JPA tutorial, and read the javadoc of the JPA annotations. Guessing the one to use shouldn't be so hard. This is as basic JPA stuff as it could be. Will you ask here each time you'll have to do something new?

Comment: See answer, this is not straight jpa but a jpa/playframework related question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well actually might not be that straightforward if you are new to play framework.

Play uses the Model class which extends GenericModel which in turn extends JPABase.
The model class enhances the entity with it's own Id.

So if your entity has it's own primary key, have it extend GenericModel and define your primary key with @Id:

```
public class MyEntity extends GenericModel {

   @Id
   public String code;

}
```

Comment: Works fine now, thank you. I needed the GenericModel indeed to be able to control the Id myself.

Comment: @emt14 it is straightforward if you read the manual. It's clearly explained in there, and it's just 1 short html page.

Comment: I agree, it's clear in the manual